# Laravel Spark profile picture returning 403 error

Tags: php, laravel, symlink, http-status-code-403, laravel-spark

When I update the profile picture on my Laravel (5.5) Spark (5.0) app, although it uploads the picture correctly, it does not display in the app.

My `APP_URL` entry in `.env` is correct.

I have run `php artisan storage:link`.

I have confirmed that the image in the database (`/storage/profiles/fPLKc4SXY8ivpMGublIiNtZx2ZGjdcPq7f2kAHBV.jpeg`) exists in `storage/app/profiles` and in `public/storage/profiles`.

But when I look at the Network tab in Chrome it shows a `403` error when it tries to fetch the image.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have the latest source, but this is a known issue:
https://github.com/laravel/spark/issues/593

and specifically if you want to make this change to your source files...

https://github.com/laravel/spark/commit/e163ac68919b7c29ae703dbf8cd350e4670030d8

Comment: I don't see how that's related to my problem.

Comment: Compare your src/Interactions/Settings/Profile/UpdateProfilePhoto.php and src/Interactions/Settings/Teams/UpdateTeamPhoto.php files with those posted in the link above.  Are they different?  If so, pull the new files, delete your current symlink, rerun php artisan storage:link and restart your VM.

Comment: I just mean that the bug in the issue you linked is about images not being stored correctly. For me the correct image is on the server and is being referenced correctly in the database. I am getting a `403` error.

Comment: Also make sure your APP_URL is set appropriately -- mine is set to sample.test instead of localhost.  Also take a look at the record in the users table and the photo_url path to make sure it matches what you have specified in your APP_URL.